# Loading modules to Angular applications

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-module

In my Angular application, I am trying to use [angular4-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker). As they have mentioned in their documentation they are importing their module like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyTestApp } from './my-test-app';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, MyDatePickerModule ],
    declarations: [ MyTestApp ],
    bootstrap:    [ MyTestApp ]
})
export class MyTestAppModule {}
```

But when I am importing `mydatepicker` like that I am getting an error:

> Cannot find module 'mydatepicker'.

Instead I have to give path to the node module it self.

```
import { MyDatePickerModule } from '../../../../../node_modules/angular4-datepicker/src/my-date-picker';
```

How do I load that module like that they have mentioned in their documentation?

Comment: Use this package: https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker

Comment: @D.Simon no the package works fine actually. i just wanted to know how to load a module or a component like that without giving the path.

Comment: Yes I know but it's the exact same package except that the import works like expected. See https://github.com/AmolBorse/mydatepicker/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this syntax `import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';` means you have a module exported called mydatepicker. [Typescript import/export official documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Seems the error you are pointing has been reported on Github's repo: [Github Date Picker issue and solutions](https://github.com/AmolBorse/mydatepicker/issues/1)

Hope this helps ;)